# PhantomJS with wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

I know it sounds basic but I'd really appreciate some help/guidence on how to use phantomjs on my wordpress project. I'm using Windows 8.1 and local host with xampp for now. I've downloaded phantomjs and already tested it via command prompt and got the result (pdf) I want. Now I'd like to use it on my WP project but not sure how to get it started. I've tried to copy phantomjs folder to my wp-content/plugins folder and run exec command but no results at all.

I know there're lots of examples out there on how to run phantomjs but I couldn't find anything for wp.